# How do I find $P(X_1 > X_2,...X_n)$ if all variables are independent?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, stochastic-analysis

Specifically, I have an estimation for all $X$ where $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mu_i,\sigma_i\right)$.

Comment: If $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ then the variance of $X_i$ is $\sigma_i^2$.

Comment: Clarified with edit

Comment: The integral to estimate is a little cumbersome: $$\begin{align}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2}\sigma_1\cdot\ldots\cdot\sigma_n}&\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-\tfrac{(x_1-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma^2_1}}\Big(\int^{x_1}_{-\infty}e^{-\tfrac{(x_2-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma^2_2}}\,dx_2\ldots\int^{x_1}_{-\infty} e^{-\tfrac{(x_n-\mu_n)^2}{2\sigma^2_n}}\,dx_n\Big)\,dx_1\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2_1}}\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-\tfrac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma^2_1}}\prod^n_{j=2}\Phi\big(\tfrac{x-\mu_j}{\sigma_j}\big)\,dx
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You need the variances for any kind of reasonable estimate / bound.  The means alone are not enough.  In the following let $E$ be your desired event $X_1 > X_2, \dots, X_n$.

E.g. say $\mu_i = 1 + \mu_{i+1}$ i.e. they are already ranked and the gaps are all size $1$.  Consider these scenarios:

- If all $\sigma_i \ll 1$ then the means dominate and the distributions are well separated: $P(E) \approx 1$.
- If all $\sigma_i \gg n$ then the means don't really matter and all $n$ distributions overlap a lot: $P(E) \approx 1/n$ by symmetry.
- If $\sigma_1 \gg n$ and all other $\sigma_i \ll 1$ then it really just depends on what $X_1$ is doing: $P(E) \approx 1/2$ because if $X_1 > \mu_1$ then $E$ is very likely, while if $X_1 < \mu_1$ then $E$ is very unlikely.